# Local Storage Not Working As Expected

Tags: javascript, cordova, local-storage, phonegap-build

I built an app that I then built with PhoneGap Build.THe purpose is for it to run a code (starts at `var Quotes` once per day when the app is loaded).

When debugging why it wasn't working I noticed that in console I was getting back my message "Local storage didn't work". This means that my initial `localstorage.getItem` which is supposed to make sure the local storage can be read is returning `null`. So my code never gets executed.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function onDeviceReady() { //Do something when the app on device is loaded

var localVal = localStorage.getItem('DateOpened'); 

if(localVal  == null){ 

   console.log("LocalStorage did not work...")}

else
{
  var tempd = new Date(); //Get today's date
  var str = tempd.getDay() + tempd.getMonth() + tempd.getFullYear();
  if(localVal.localeCompare(str) == -1) 
              { 
                            var Quotes = [];
                            var ID = [];
                            var Tag = [];
                            var seen = [];

    localStorage.setItem('DateOpened',str);
    console.log("The App Ran, you can get a new fat tomorrow");
    console.log("Todays date:" + str);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, there will be no `DateOpened` item in local storage, so your code will follow the "did not work" branch, because `getItem` returns `null` for things that don't exist. That branch never sets anything in `DateOpened`, so...you'll always follow that branch.

The fix is not to skip over your code setting `DateOpened` if the device has local storage.

---

There's also an unrelated problem: Your `var str = tempd.getDay() + tempd.getMonth() + tempd.getFullYear()` does **not** produce a string, it produces a number formed by *adding* those values together, since they're all numbers. Your later `localeCompare` will fail because it's not a string. You also have the fields in the wrong order for a meaningful textual comparison — you need year first, then month, then day.

---

Here's a minimal fix, see comments:

```
function onDeviceReady() {

    var tempd = new Date();
    // Note that by adding strings in there, we end up with a string instead of adding.
    // Note the order: Year first, then month, then day.
    // Also, since we display it, we put separators in and add 1 to month (since Jan = 0).
    var str = tempd.getFullYear() + "-" + (tempd.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + tempd.getDay();
    var localVal = localStorage.getItem('DateOpened');

    // If we have no stored value, or it's more than a day old by your definition,
    // do your stuff and store the new date
    if (localVal == null || localVal.localeCompare(str) < 0) {
        var Quotes = [];
        var ID = [];
        var Tag = [];
        var seen = [];

        localStorage.setItem('DateOpened', str);
        console.log("The App Ran, you can get a new fat tomorrow");
        console.log("Todays date:" + str);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a suspicious that since localVar was never set it would also be null. Thanks TJ, I will see if this works.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is help full for you.

```js
function onDeviceReady() { //Do something when the app on device is loaded

var localVal = localStorage.getItem('DateOpened'); 

if (typeof(DateOpened) == "undefined") 

   console.log("LocalStorage did not work...")}

else
{
  var tempd = new Date(); //Get today's date
  var str = tempd.getDay() + tempd.getMonth() + tempd.getFullYear();
  var allRecords=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("DateOpened"));     
  if(allRecords == -1) 
              { 
                            var Quotes = [];
                            var ID = [];
                            var Tag = [];
                            var seen = [];

    localStorage.setItem('DateOpened',str);
    console.log("The App Ran, you can get a new fat tomorrow");
    console.log("Todays date:" + str);
  }
 }
}
```